# Shapes with several focus points

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

I recently understood the meaning of focus points and how to abuse them for generating some fun games like Loop. (Reading pool backwards)

In Loop one uses a pool table in the shape of an ellipse and puts the hole in of its focus points. Thus one can always hole a ball by making it go through its other focus point.

I believe in 2-dimensional there are just ellipse to have this property, also that an object can't have more than 2 focus points. However I cannot prove it.

Therefore I would like to read up on that topic. I am particularly interested, which kind of properties an n-dimensional shape, table or whatever has to fulfill for it to have 2,3 or more focus points.

As always thanks in advance for any constructive comment or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I believe in $2$ dimensions there are just ellipses that have this property, also that an object can't have more than $2$ focus points.*

You believe wrongly ! You can have as many foci as you want, even in $2$D, and the shape thus obtained is called an [*n*-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) or a “multifocal ellipse”. My advice to you is to do what I did: Go to the [*Desmos*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) page, draw two points at $(\pm1,0)$, and a third one of variable coordinates which is mobile $($you will have to use sliders$)$. Then type in the equation of the $3$-ellipse, and modify the position of the last point to inspect its behavior.

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed very interesting. I didn't expect the "math of focus points" to be so overseeable. Well, now I have something read and maybe I can come up with a nice problem. Thanks again.