# Is the Locus circle?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, circles, conic-sections, locus

Locus of points such that sum of it's distances of them from four fixed points remains constant? 
Is the locus circle?
I was not able to solve it as there were four radicals.
Is it a theorem?

Comment: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Tri.Locus/FourPt/FourPt.html

Answer (score 1):

> *Is the locus a circle ?*

In general, no. It is a [multifocal ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse). More [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483195) on this topic can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405834), along with a [video](https://www.flickr.com/photos/letterror/9015470501) showing how to actually draw one.